# BigQuery - Uploading GZIP compressed files using Java Client library

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to upload gzip compressed files using Google's BigQuery Java client API. I am able to upload normal files without any issue. But gzip fails with the error "Invalid content type 'application/x-gzip'. Uploads must have content type 'application/octet-stream'".

Below is my code.

```
val pid = "****"
val dsid = "****"
val tid = "****"
val br = Source.fromFile(new File("****")).bufferedReader()
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
val schemaFields = mapper.readValue(br, classOf[util.ArrayList[TableFieldSchema]])
val tschema = new TableSchema().setFields(schemaFields)
val tr = new   TableReference().setProjectId(pid).setDatasetId(dsid).setTableId(tid)

val jc = new JobConfigurationLoad().setDestinationTable(tr)
  .setSchema(tschema)
  .setSourceFormat("NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON")
  .setCreateDisposition("CREATE_IF_NEEDED")
  .setWriteDisposition("WRITE_APPEND")
  .setIgnoreUnknownValues(true)

val fmr = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss-SSS")
val now = fmr.format(new Date())

val loadJob = new Job().setJobReference(new JobReference().setJobId(Joiner.on("-")
  .join("INSERT", pid, dsid, tid, now))
  .setProjectId(pid))
  .setConfiguration(new JobConfiguration().setLoad(jc))

//  val data = new FileContent(MediaType.OCTET_STREAM.toString, new   File("/Users/jegan/sessions/34560-6"))  // This works.

val data = new FileContent(MediaType.GZIP.toString, new   File("/Users/jegan/sessions/34560-6"))

val bq = BQHelper.createAuthorizedClientWithDefaultCredentials()

val job = bq.jobs().insert(pid, loadJob, data).execute()
```

And from this link, I see that we need to use resumable upload to achieve this.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-post-request#resumable

But the issue is, I am using the Java Client library from Google. How to do resumable upload using this library? There seems to be not much information on this regard or I am missing something. Has anyone ever done this? Please point me to some documentation/samples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If application/octet-stream works, just use that. We don't use the media type for anything important.

That said, I thought I changed it so that we'd accept any media type. Are you using the most recent version of the Java client library?

Comment: Thanks for your response Jeremy. octet-stream actually works. I was manually unzipping the file before. After reading your response, I tried without converting and it actually works. I remember reading somewhere that the API does not support gzip format and got carried away with that. Sorry about that. Thanks for your help.